# Show selected fields of table as per given product

Tags: c#, database

1. We have a table Products{{ProductID(PK) ,name, Description} } which store name of products
2. Table Products_Manufacturing {ProductID(FK) ,A,B,C,D,E}   stores fields value of multiple products ,But not all product have all columns.
   For example

   ```
          Product_A  have {A,B,C} 
          Product_B  have  {A,D,E}
   ```
3. we are making a one table with same field like  Products_Manufacturing [ProductID(FK) ,A,B,C,D,E]

   Table(ProductsFieldSelection) {ProductID(FK),A,B,C,D,E}
                                      ProductID is foriegn key (unique)[Products]

   When we create new product then system will shows
   all fields of table(ProductsFieldSelection) fields and user will selects 
   required fields per product. System will saves these field name in ProductsFieldSelection table .

   ```
                               A,B,C,D,E ==>dataType[bool]
   ```

   Add new product Product_A

   ```
                Name ==(varchar)
                Description==(varchar)
                A(bool)  ==true
                B(bool)  ==true
                C(bool)  ==true
                D(bool)  ==false
                E(bool)  ==false
   ```

In this situation ,i want design a database system which  remember fields of  product . Is it correct correct way to handle this situation or any other idea ??

Comment: have table with all columns and insert `null` if the value doesn't exists.

Comment: yes , i am doing same way.

Comment: @Bharadwaj I have seen tables designed like this, with 900+ columns, of which 85% of the columns are null.  This approach causes headaches later and is time consuming to refactor.  I'd recommend using product classes (e.g. fruit or vehicle instead of product) so that you have more columns in common and a greater density of column usage

Comment: I am use same approach as mentioned .First i made master table which common fields   and then two sub type table like fruit and vehicle .But some fruit have common fields and as well as some different fields . I will save all fruits in fruitTable ,But i will allow  to user to select extra option per selected fruit .

Comment: @WesH Does it look ok ?? Make one table  for each Fruit/vehicle  makes any sense.??

Comment: The design you described in your question is very flexible, but it can also be very hard to make good use of.  Your queries will be very complicated and you'll frequently be battling performance problems (you have to query for the object to know which fields you want to filter on).  I have had to support systems that were implemented that way and I HATED working with it.  It can work, but I think you're trading a reduction in design and development time for an increase in support and maintenance.  For me, I prefer to invest my time in developing new solutions, not support existing solutions.

Comment: you are right .But my client doesn't want to update Code with every new products.

Comment: As long as they understand the solution may be harder to support and maintain, reports may take longer to develop and may not perform as well, and training new dev/support staff may take longer.  

Try it for yourself.  Create a few different products and then create a query that accurately retrieves and labels the columns used for a specific product.  Then do the same for a different product.

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggestion .I will try to apply your advice.