# One table for different products with same fields but with different data range?

Tags: c#, database-design

I want to stores many different products in my database(as well as in one table). With help of inheritance (Table per Concrete Type) ,i am keeping all common fields(date,customer,orderID) in parent table and made one child table for one product .

one child table => it holds many different product with same and different fields

```
           ProductOne = {A,B,**C**}
           ProductTwo = {A,B,**D**}
           ProductThree ={A,B,**F**}
```

Now i made TableAllProduct and Field of tables are {A,B,C,D,F}

To reason to select this design ,because i am thinking about my future new product ,For example if we got new product with these exist fields{A,B,C,D,F} ,so we should able to store new product data in TableAllProduct table without any software upgrade (instead create new table as per Inheritance approach which required new code)

TableAllProduct can hold three different product ProductOne = {A,B,C} ProductTwo = {A,B,D} ProductThree ={A,B,F}

Next step is stores Data in TableAllProduct

As per given scenario, ProductOne and ProductTwo have common field {A,B} But A field stores data from ProductOne as well as for ProductTwo

ProductOne have following option=={data__A_1,data__A_2 ,data__A_3}

ProductTwo have following option =={data__B_1,data__B_2 }
which i brings from other table (Manny to Manny)

Here we breaks rules of RDBMS ,Because I need multiple foreign key at one column ,But RDBMS doesn't supports , To delete/edit of foreign key responsibilities/function can done with DELETE_trigger(which will check record in Category table )

In this way , i can stores multiple product in table for now and future.

What is disadvantage of this approach ?

Is there any other possibilities solutions to solve this problem with better way .(I know about Entity–attribute–value model ,but in our situation ,product doesn't not changes daily /weekly bases and EVA is too complex to maintain).Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to normalize your data.

The model you've described can work.  You need to have the AllProducts table only contain the attributes(columns) in common for all of the products.  Attributes like name and SKU, and maybe a reference to the vendor/supplier.

Once you have identified the common attributes, the remaining attributes can be moved into a table specific to each product.  The SpecificProduct table can use the PK of the AllProducts table as a PK and FK.  Every record in SpecificProduct will also have a record in the AllProducts table.  The complete data for a specific product consists of the attributes from the AllProducts table joined to the columns for the specific product table.

This strategy helps to keep the AllProducts table width small when a varied subset of attributes relates to a small subset of the records in the table.  By reusing the AllProducts PK as the PK/FK of the specific products table, you ensure joins performance will be good as well.

Comment: I have more than  200 product  with common attributes but with different data(options) . With your scenario ,i need to create 200 tables . In future,  every new product(same attributes) ,i will have to create new table which take extra development   time .

Comment: I already have AllProducts and  SpecificProduct table. But i want  SpecificProduct table should hold more than one products.Thanks

Comment: As long as the data types are the same, you can put different information in the same column.  However, I think you'll find that much more complicated to develop against and support then the overhead of creating a table for each product.  If you do overload your column definitions, you may as well use generic columns names, columnA, columnB, etc, since the name of the column won't actually describe the data.  200 tables may sound like a big deal, but you only have to pay that cost once.  Redefining the meaning of a column based on the row will cause you headaches for a long time.

Comment: Column name can be same in between  ProductA(A,B,C) and  ProductB(A;B;C;) .But  ProductA  's Coulmn A has range(1,2,3) and   ProductB  's Coulmn A has range( 9,12,23).

Comment: If we go with your strategy ,Now we have 200 product (tables) .It works for now , But next month, if we will have new product with similar column .Then again we have create new table ??

Comment: If ProductA and ProductB have the same collection of attributes, they can be of the same class of Product and share a table.  If the attributes differ, they should be a different class, and stored in separate product tables.

Comment: If you combine all of your products in the same table, rather than separate tables, every time you add a new product, you'll have to confirm that the logic to handle all of the other product are handled appropriately for that new products columns.  In addition, if you add a brand new column for a single product, you'll be adding that column to every product.  There is a trade-off for both solutions, it just depends on where you want to spend your time.  I would rather create a new table for a new product class, knowing I won't affect any other products.

Comment: Thanks a  for time and suggestions.It means a lot for me to take decision . I would go with Onetable with same column name (different data range) .I know that code complexity is very high at start time ,But it can adjust many new similar product with same columns[different data range] .

Comment: Can you look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48380421/show-selected-fields-of-table-as-per-given-product?noredirect=1#comment83747508_48380421

Comment: It is also part of same database design where user can select  number of column for one product.